# Regular Expression not working in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the string `"SELECTOR('(namespace=''ar.com.osde.reintegros'' and eventname=''generacionReintegro'')')"`.

I need return the string that is between `"SELECTOR("` and `")"`, the result should be: `'(namespace=''ar.com.osde.reintegros'' and eventname=''generacionReintegro'')'`.

My code with the regular expression is:

```
public static String extractSelector(String txt){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^SELECTOR\\((.*)\\)$");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(txt);
    String s = null;
    while (m.find()) {
        s = m.group(1);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Where txt = `"SELECTOR('(namespace=''ar.com.osde.reintegros'' and eventname=''generacionReintegro'')')"`

But this always return `null`. Why is that?

Comment: This code looks ok, the problem is probably elsewhere in your code

Comment: Your code works: http://ideone.com/0SnJKM

Comment: Could it be that you have a hidden character or a space at the end or the beginning of your string? Try using `txt.trim()` instead of just `txt`.

Comment: I don't really think this is a duplicate question. At least not a duplicate of the question it's marked as a duplicate of.

Answer (score -1):

This [**jdoodle**](http://jdoodle.com/a/i8) demonstrates that that part of the code works (only added a declaration for `txt` and removed the `return` statement). Are you sure there is nothing done with the `txt` before that?

Given your code, the only explanation is that `txt` does not match the pattern fully... This because the `while`-loop is not executed at all (thus `find` is always false).

Perhaps there are spaces between `SELECTOR` and the opening bracket `(`, perhaps `SELECTOR` can be put in lowercase. In order to debug this, you can perhaps write

```
System.out.println("\""+txt+"\"");
```

Before actually matching it, or use the debugger features of your IDE to do this. The quotes are used to make the spaces more explicit.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @BrandonBuck: updated it with advice on how to debug. Since it provides ways to fully diagnose the problem, this is more than a comment...

Comment: If it doesn't provide a means to resolve the problem (debugging isn't an answer, it's a recommendation) it's still not an answer.

Comment: @BrandonBuck: It does, the only possible reason why this doesn't work is because the while loop isn't executed. That's the only possible explanation because if `txt` was not effective, it would give a `NullPointerException`. The objective of SO is not to resolve problems. It is to share knowledge Q/A-like. That's one of the things people don't tend to pick up.